# A property of AWS Amplify Graphql schema is missing even though it does exist

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using AWS Amplify and want to add new data into AWS AppSync. Below is the schema that I have:

```
type Product
    @model
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "userId" }, { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"] }]) {
    id: Int
    userId: ID
    owner: String
    title: String
}

type UpsellRule
    @model
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "userId" }, { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"] }]) {
    id: String
    userId: ID
    owner: String
    name: String
    subscriptionProducts: [Product]
    upsellProducts: [Product]
}
```

Based on that schema, this is the mutation that I have to add a new item:

```
const createUpsellRule = `mutation CreateUpsellRule($input: CreateUpsellRuleInput!) {
    createUpsellRule(input: $input) {
        id
        userId
        owner
        name
        subscriptionProducts {
            id
            userId
            owner
            title
        }
        upsellProducts {
            id
            userId
            owner
            title
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of the payload that I sent:

```
{
  id: '<a-unique-id>',
  userId: '<a-unique-userId>',
  owner: '<an-owner>',
  subscriptionProducts: [{
      userId: '89217803-5fff-44d9-93af-e72b05012813',
      owner: '<an-owner>',
      id: 4448795164753,
      name: 'Product 10'
    },
    {
      userId: '89217803-5fff-44d9-93af-e72b05012813',
      owner: '<an-owner>',
      id: 4448795656273,
      name: 'Product 11'
    }
  ],
  upsellProducts: [{
    userId: '89217803-5fff-44d9-93af-e72b05012813',
    owner: '<an-owner>',
    id: 4448796573777,
    title: 'Product 13'
  }],
  name: 'ALL'
}
```

Using above schema, mutation, and payload, I got an error that saying `subscriptionProducts` field is not defined. To make sure that the schema is correct, I try to exclude `subscriptionProducts` and `upsellProducts` and it successfully added into AppSync. When I try to get it again from the AppSync, it shown me `subscriptionProducts` and `upsellProducts` properties which have null as a value. Do anyone of you know what is the correct mutation / payload that I should use based on the schema above?

PS: I am using `aws-appsync` as a client library

Comment: In your mutation, subscriptionProducts does not have the property name. It has title instead?

Comment: @Sunny I see. I try to fix that and it works now. 
Is that error expected? I don't think the error message is clear enough with the issue itself.

Comment: Yes i think the error is expected because the properties do not match.

Comment: Can you provide the `CreateUpsellRuleInput!` type?